# Electric susceptibility in matter $E(t)= E_0 \delta(t-t_0)$

Tags: electromagnetism, fourier-transform, polarization

I have few questions about the Electric susceptibility in matter.

First of all, the example begins with $E(t)= E_0 \delta(t-t_0)$.
I'm not sure what does it means. My guess is that the electric field is only present at $t=t_0$. Kind of a pulsation?

Furthermore, I know that $$\chi(\omega) = \frac{ne^2}{m\epsilon_0(\omega_0^2 - \omega^2)- i\omega \gamma}$$

Thus, using the Fourier transform to get $\chi(\tau)$
$$\chi(\tau) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{ne^2 e^{-i \omega \tau}}{m\epsilon_0(\omega_0^2 - \omega^2)- i\omega \gamma} d \omega$$

We can see that we have 2 poles, $\omega_{1,2} = \frac{-i\gamma}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{-\gamma^2}{4} + \omega_0^2}$

I have this result without further explanation : for $\tau < 0$, there's no pole, thus the integral is 0. I'm not sure to understand this result.

If $\tau < 0$, the exponential is positive and then the integral goes to infinity, so how is possible that the integral is 0.

Comment: It's zero because you don't have poles in the upper plane. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma

Comment: @user250057 Is it because both poles are in the negatives imaginaries?
$\omega_{1,2} = \frac{-i\gamma}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{-\gamma^2}{4} + \omega_0^2}$, both poles are $\frac{-i \gamma}{2}$

Comment: Yes, because when $\tau<0$ you integrate in the upper plane but, as you noticed, there aren't poles so the integral is zero.